# What do the numbers before test testcase in Test lab indicate?

Tags: hp-quality-center

What do the numbers before test testcase in Test lab indicate? For example:

```
[1]Login with ur……
```

What does the `[1]` mean?

Comment: HP now calls quality center as ALM however on SO ALM refers to [Application Life cycle Management in general](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/alm/info). It is not the same as qc or hp-quality-center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `[1]` before the test case in the test lab indicates the number of occurrences of that test case. If you add the same test case twice it will look something like this.

```
[1] Test Case Name
[2] Test Case Name
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's the number of instances of that test case in the Execution Grid.
each time you add this test case to the grid you get a new instance added with a new number beside it.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to understand instances of test 'cases'.  I was thinking of it all wrong (because the test lab is where you run the tests, right?).
When you want a specific set of parameters for a test, use test configurations in the Test Plan.
Once the values are set, you create your instance in the Test Lab from the configuration so that you can execute it.
If, on the other hand, you have an instance in Test Lab with some specific values that you like, you can use right-click -> generate configuration.
This creates a configuration for you and you can give it a name of your choosing (something that I really wanted to do in the test lab, until I discovered how Configurations work).
There is also a button in the test plan configurations tab to 'push' updated values to the Test Lab.  So while there is a disconnect between configurations and test lab (by design), but it is not such a disconnect that you can't connect them when you want.